# MPI Python not enough slots

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi

I'm currently new in using MPI for python with Open MPI and I have the following issue :

When I try to run a simple script with mpiexec -np 7 mpitest.py I have the following error :

> There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 7
>   slots that were requested by the application: python Either request
>   fewer slots for your application, or make more slots available for
>   use.

I don't understand, I have a 12 processor computer with 6 core per socket (1 socket per processor), so this would mean I would be able to run up to 72 threads but OpenMPI get stuck at 6.

Any idea how to take advantage of all processors ?

Comment: This is very odd... which Open MPI version ? What does `mpirun --report-bindings -np 3 hostname` says ?

Comment: 1 socket per processor does not make sense. How many nodes ? Socket per node ? Core per socket ? Thread per core ? If hwloc is installed, can you run `lstopo` ?

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of MPI, oversubscribing can help. Use the --oversubscribe switch as follows:

```
mpiexec --oversubscribe -np 7 mpitest.py
```